# Calling android widget method of Activity class from another class?

Tags: android

i wanna call a method of Activity Class to normal public class. but it faced **NullPointerException**.

**My Activty (Lv.class)**

```
public class Lv extends Activity {
        public static EditText et1; 
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.listandimage);
            et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

**My Public class (Data.class)**

```
        public class Data {             
            public String c = "";
            public String d = "";
            private static Socket soc;

            public Data(String var1, String var2) {
                this.c = var1.toLowerCase().trim();
                this.d = var2;
            }

    public final void start() {

            try {
                soc = new Socket(address, port);
                os = soc.getOutputStream();
                is = new DataInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
            } catch (Exception var5) {
            }
    }

        public void processdata(String rcvdata){
String txttype = rcvdata;
        if (txttype.equals("\003")) {
                        String rname="my man";
                        Lv.et1.setText(rname);
    }
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        new RTask().execute();
    }
});
class RTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... Void) {
        try {
            mee = new Data(editText1.getText().toString(), editText2
                    .getText().toString());
            mee.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

`Data.class` is a public class which sythesize data received from socket connection.
Yes.my layout name,content name is ok,when i use that from `activity button onclick`,it works.
Somehow,every command of activity class

(e.g gettext,button on click,Calling adapter notify[made them `public static` also]) 
via this public class will remain **NullPointerException**.

please help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: Could you provide more code? For exmple when your Data class is initialized? 
As your et1 variable is static it is  possible that your data class instance is just accessing that variable before it is initialized. You should not use static references to your views - to prevent memory leaks.
You should rathter call some method on your activity that will set the text. I guess your socket connection data are delivered on worker thread, but the `setText()` method should be called on UI-Thread (see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))

Comment: **I guess your socket connection data are delivered on worker thread, but the setText() method should be called on UI-Thread**

yes,that socket connection works on thread from MainActivity.class where `Data.class` is socket class to call a socket and its not a UI-thread also. :(      @convexHull

Comment: so how i call UI thread method from a non-activity class which run through asynctask of MainActivity.class?? @convexHull

Comment: RTask is inner class of MainActivity? Provide complete code of MainActivity.class and Lv.class

(Anyway, you definitely shouldn't use static memebers as references to View components!!! That is realy bad design)

Comment: Yes,bro,its inner class to execute socket(i added),and about `Lv.class`,it just an activity with one `EditText` and i have to use this normal class (Data.class) to control others Activity.class. **by the way,i use TabActivity for other Activity except MainActivity** @convexHull

Answer (score 0):

1. In your case you shouldnt set `EditText` as **static**.
2. Pass this `EditText` to your Data class. So you can call it inside Data class.

   ```
   class Data {
       //make it field
       private EditText editText;
       //your constructor of Data class
       Data (EditText editText) {
       this.editText = editText;
       }
       //now you can use editText like you are in Activity
       private myMethod() {
       editText.setText("every String you want to see here");
       }
   }
   ```

Now when you create Data from Activity just pass EditText

```
Data data = new Data(editText);
```

Same way in you need to pass `Activity`.

If you need to change more than one `EditText` inside your Data class its better to pass activity into it. Then create multiple public methods to change values of views.

First of all you should know that static variable is linked to **class**, not to object. So for sure its null for you in your case because `onCreate` method where you initialize `EditText` is not static.

Comment: can you give an example how i pass `EditText or Activity` through my `Data.class` ? @DEADMC

Comment: thanks for your reply,but there is some confusion,`EditText` already created on `Lv(Activity.class)`,On data receiving process when my `Data.class` receive a specific data that i want, i wanna change `EditText` value by `.setText` method from `Data.class`. @DEADMC

Comment: exacty, its created in Lv class so you need to pass it to Data class. The question is where do you create Data class. Probably you need to show more code.

Comment: `Data.class` is a separate class file `Data.java`,its like socket module @DEADMC

Comment: sorry guys,i think i figure out that,its about my lacking of knowledge on android development.actually my project is goes through `MainActivity(login) > TabActivity(contains 4 activity - L1,L2,Lv,Lu). ` Lv is non visible activity,i think it is the problem and i have to embedded `Data.class` to any activity as `inner class`. I did not manage multiple activity before that's why it make me confused. @convexHull @DEADMC